# Срочно!!!! Стили страницы входа через google (django-allauth) | Django

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

Я использую django-allauth что бы сделать вход через google в django, у меня все работает и все супер, но страницы sign up и sign in они выглядят сыро и некрасиво, подскажите как добавить стилей к этим страницам

**Sign up:**

[image: sign up google]

**Sign in:**

[image: sign in google]

**И еще какая то страница:**

[image: login with google]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.allauth.org/en/latest/common/templates.html

Скопируй  allauth/templates  в папку BASE_DIR / "templates" и там исправляй как нравится

Comment: Спасибо большое